# Why isn't there a gold badge for participating in moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, badges, election

I am curious to know why there isn't a gold badge for participating in many elections on a site.

I understand that there is a recurring bronze 'Caucus' badge and recurring silver 'Constituent' badge for various stages of a site's election. I am curious to know why there isn't a gold badge for continuous participation in elections?

Note, I am not suggesting that there needs to be a gold badge, but as stated, I am curious as to why there isn't one in existence.

Comment: What counts as "participation" for this ribbon?

Comment: As stated, repeatedly, I am **not** requesting a badge

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=gold+badge+election+is%3Aq

Comment: The obvious reason for there being no gold badge is "nobody requested one with sufficient justification" and, perhaps more to the point, "badges do not automatically come in matched sets of three scaling requirements". If you can't imagine any reason why a gold election badge would be a good thing, doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: I am becoming increasingly sorry to have asked in the first place, to be honest.  Was just curious.

Answer (score 10):

For me, a gold badge resembles extensive, good contributions to the site. Earning a gold badge for participating in an election is too much if you ask me.  What exemplar behavior does a user earning that badge show? Just having enough reputation to participate in an election doesn't justify a gold badge in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Arguably the gold badge for participating in moderator elections is **Sheriff**, awarded to winners who serve for at least a year.